# Is there an operator for inequality in SMT-Lib?

Tags: z3, smt, smt-lib

I know I can assert inequality with simple `(not (= a b))`, but I wonder if there is a operator that does this directly. I have tried everything that came to my mind including `!=`, `<>`, `\=` (this doesn't parse), `/=`, `=/=`, `neq` and none of them works.

Is there a dedicated function for it or do I need to compose equality with negation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is called `distinct`, See section 3.7.1 of https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

Note that `distinct` can take an arbitrary number of arguments. For instance:

```
(assert (distinct x y z))
```

means:

```
(assert (and (distinct x y) (distinct x z) (distinct y z)))
```